# Simple toy OS memory management

Tags: memory-management, kernel, osdev

I'm developing a simple little toy OS in C and assembly as an experiment, but I'm starting to worry myself with my lack of knowledge on system memory.

I've been able to compile the kernel, run it in Bochs (loaded by GRUB), and have it print "Hello, world!"  Now I'm off trying to make a simple memory manager so I can start experimenting with other things.

I found some resources on memory management, but they didn't really have enough code to go off of (as in I understood the concept, but I was at a loss for actually knowing how to implement it).

I tried a few more or less complicated strategies, then settled with a ridiculously simplistic one (just keep an offset in memory and increase it by the size of the allocated object) until the need arises to change.  No fragmentation control, protection, or anything, yet.

So I would like to know where I can find more information when I do need a more robust manager.  And I'd also like to learn more about paging, segmentation, and other relevant things.  So far I haven't dealt with paging at all, but I've seen it mentioned often in OS development sites, so I'm guessing I'll have to deal with it sooner or later.

I've also read about some form of indirect pointers, where an application holds a pointer that is redirected by the memory manager to its real location.  That's quite a ways off for me, I'm sure, but it seems important if I ever want to try virtual memory or defragmentation.

And also, where am I supposed to put my memory offset?  I had no idea what the best spot was, so I just randomly picked `0x1000`, and I'm sure it's going to come back to me later when I overwrite my kernel or something.

I'd also like to know what I should expect performance-wise (e.g. a big-O value for allocation and release) and what a reasonable ratio of memory management structures to actual managed memory would be.

Of course, feel free to answer just a subset of these questions.  Any feedback is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

If you don't know about it already, http://wiki.osdev.org/ is a good resource in general, and has multiple articles on memory management. If you're looking for a particular memory allocation algorithm, I'd suggest reading up on the "buddy system" method (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buddy_memory_allocation). I think you can probably find an example implementation on the Internet. If you can find a copy in a library, it's also probably worth reading the section of The Art Of Computer Programming dedicated to memory management (Volume 1, Section 2.5).

I don't know where you should put the memory offset (to be honest I've never written a kernel), but one thing that occurred to me which might work is to place a static variable at the end of the kernel, and start allocations after that address. Something like:

```
(In the memory manager)
extern char endOfKernel;
... (also in the memory manager)
myOffset = &endOfKernel;
... (at the end of the file that gets placed last in the binary)
char endOfKernel;
```

I guess it goes without saying, but depending on how serious you get about the operating system, you'll probably want some books on operating system design, and if you're in school it wouldn't hurt to take an OS class.

Comment: Placing your heap after the kernel is an option, but you also need to decide if the kernel you are creating is going to be run in Real or Protected mode as well.  If you are in Real mode you only have access to 1MB of memory, in protected you have potential access to the full 32-bit memory space.

Comment: Thanks!  The osdev wiki is actually how I got started.  And it looks like buddy's a good one.  It sounds like a great idea, but would you know how to place the variable at the end of the kernel?  Perhaps write a C file, and modify my linker file to be sure that file is placed at the end?

Comment: @linuxuser27 - I knew *about* real and protected modes, but I didn't realize that would cause such a difference.  Is that memory limit because real mode doesn't do paging for you?  Is there a way I could tell, like, would you happen to know if GRUB loads into real or protected mode?

Comment: No.  Paging is a mechanism that is offered to you for utilizing memory that is not really there.  I would read here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_mode and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protected_mode.  In fact, you can look at my OS (work in progress) to see how to get to protected mode: https://bitbucket.org/linuxuser27/os373.

Comment: @alecRN It sounds like that should work, though you should definitely test it for yourself. I would think if you put your special "end-of-kernel" file last in the list you send to the linker, it ought to be last in the binary.

@linuxuser27 Good point! I forgot about that.

Comment: So, does the memory manager simply select blocks for a program to be able to use, and the program manages the memory within the block itself?  My first impression was that it was the OS's memory manager that allocated each individual `malloc` call, or is that wrong?

Comment: You can put symbols directly in the linker script, so you don't need to actually force a source file to the end if you just add "endOfKernel = .;" at the end of the SECTIONS part of your linker script.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using GCC with LD, you can create a linker script that defines a symbol at the end of the .BSS section (which would give you the complete size of the kernel's memory footprint).  Many kernels in fact use this value as a parameter for GRUB's AOUT_KLUDGE header.

See http://wiki.osdev.org/Bare_bones#linker.ld for more details, note the declaration of the `ebss` symbol in the linker script.